# CSS transition property does not take effect on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

This is my first question on stack exchange so feel free to let me know if I haven't included enough information. I've looked for a solution to my particular issue and found nothing relevant so here goes...

I'm trying to achieve a sidebar navigation that slides in upon a menu button being pressed. The rest of the page should slide with it so it flows smoothly. I have used some simple javascript to toggle on/off a .active class for the navigation sidebar div and the content-wrap div. For reference, this is what I'm trying to do: http://antrikshy.com/. The transition property is applied to both the sidebar div and content-wrap element but is only affecting the navigation bar. After inspecting the webpage, I can see the css properties have been applied to the content-wrap element successfully, but they don't work. This has been tested in safari and firefox with no change in results.

See the Pen [sidebar transition example](https://codepen.io/nbuzanis/pen/oexpVQ/) on CodePen.

Here is the individual css on the content-wrap:

```
.content-wrap {
    position: relative;
    transition: all ease 2.5s;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You should include the relevant html and css. Even try something on Codepen.io or jsfiddle.net for a working example. Thank you.

Comment: Just added, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define both sides of the transition. If you are transitioning on `left` you need the `left` attribute of 0 so the transition has a starting point.

```
.content-wrap {
    position: relative;
    transition: all ease 2.5s;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
  left:0 /* THIS */
}
```

On my browser that fixes your pen -- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvKQxR.